# Вывести диапазон в массиве

Tags: c#, массивы, asp

Есть задание: В программу нужно ввести массив `A`, целых чисел. Далее ввести целое число `B` и `C`. С генерировать массив `Y` (без использования `list<int> add` и т.д., так сказать вручную), из элементов массива `A`, которые соответствуют условию, где элемент массива `А` больше `B` и меньше С. Вывести массив значений.
Реализовал: ввод значений, конвертацию массива с `string[]` в `int[]`, сортировку по упорядочиванию, вот не могу реализовать сам выбор упорядочивания массива по диапазону от `B` до `C`. В частности метод `SortArrayMethod`. Если не трудно, помогите.

```
    public int[] InitializationArrayA(string ArrayA)
    {
        string[] sortArray = ArrayA.Split(',');
        ArrayInt = new int[sortArray.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < sortArray.Length; i++)
        {</br>
            ArrayInt[i] = Convert.ToInt32(sortArray[i]);
        }
        return ArrayInt;
    }

    public int[] trueSortArray(int[] trueSort)
    { 

        int intArrrayBuffer = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < trueSort.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < trueSort.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (trueSort[j] > trueSort[j + 1])
                {
                    intArrrayBuffer = trueSort[j + 1];
                    trueSort[j + 1] = trueSort[j];
                    trueSort[j] = intArrrayBuffer;
                }
            }
        }
        return trueSort;
    }




    public int[] SortArrayMethod(int[] sortArrayValue, int valueB, int valueC)
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < sortArrayValue.Length; i++)
        {
            
            if (sortArrayValue[i] > valueB && sortArrayValue[i] < valueC)
            {
              intArrrayBuffer[i] = sortArrayValue[i];
            }
        }
        return intArrrayBuffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: А что такое `intArrrayBuffer` внутри `SortArrayMethod`?

Comment: intArrrayBuffer - это массив в который планировалось сохранять отсортированный массив sortArrayValue

Comment: @slavkan777: а откуда код `SortArrayMethod` его знает? Это поле окружающего класса? Как оно инициализируется?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте

```
int[] A;
int[] Y = A.Where(x => (x > B || x < C));
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: код не компилируемый. Нужно либо заменить "int[] Y" на "var Y" или добавить вызов ToArray()

Answer (score 2):

Макс Жуков продемонстрировал нам функциональный подход к проблеме, я же покажу процедурный:

```
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= intArrayBuffer.Length; i++)
{
    if (sortArrayValue[i] > valueB && sortArrayValue[i] < valueC) {
        intArrrayBuffer[k++] = sortArrayValue[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Эээ... Вы уверены? Там же вроде нужны элементы со _значениями_ от `valueB` до `valueC`, а не с _индексами_ от `valueB` до `valueC`.

---
Правда, если массив упорядочен, то нам и правда нужен кусок между двумя _индексами_, но какими? Тут нужно либо во время сортировки запоминать, либо двоичный поиск использовать. При большом размере входного массива должно быть быстрее.

Comment: Прошу прощения, перепутал. Поправил код.

------

    int left = 0;
    int right = sortArrayValue.Length;
    while (left <= valueB) left++;
    while (right >= valueC) right--;
    for (int i = left; i <= right; i++) {
        intArrrayBuffer[i - left] = sortArrayValue[i];
    }

Улучшение будет заметно, если бОльшая часть массива попадает под условие выборки.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас передлеаю.

Comment: @fori1ton: можно ещё чуть соптимизировать: не искать правую границу, а выходить из цикла по достижению условия:

    int left = 0;
    while (sortArrayValue[left] <= valueB) left++;
    for (int i = left; i <= sortArrayValue.Length; i++) {
        if (sortArrayValue[i] >= valueC) break;
        intArrrayBuffer[i - left] = sortArrayValue[i];
    }

Будет полезно в случае, когда _меньшая_ часть массива попадает под условие.

Comment: @fori1ton: или даже так:

    int idx = 0;
    foreach (var v in sortArrayValue) {
        if (v <= valueB) continue;
        if (v >= valueC) break;
        intArrrayBuffer[idx++] = v;
    }

Хотя проверка `v <= valueB` будет выполняться даже тогда, когда она уже не нужна.

Answer (score 2):

Вот ещё функциональный вариант для отсортированного массива:

```
intArrrayBuffer = sortArrayValue.SkipWhile(v => v <= valueB)
                                .TakeWhile(v => v < valueC)
                                .ToArray();
```

Comment: спасибо учту